# How do you send a base64 encoded string from backend (python) to frontend(Android) using Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, base64, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a need to send a encoded String through Google CloudEndpoint. My back end is Python and front end is Android Application. I am generating the following code in the backend.

```
policy_document = '''{          
                        "expiration": "2016-06-16T11:11:11Z",
                        "conditions": [
                            ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
                            {"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },
                            {"bucket": "application.appspot.com"},
                            {"success_action_redirect": success_redirect },
                            {"success_action_status": "201"},           
                            ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg" ],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-programname", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-membername", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-tag1", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-tag2", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-tag3", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-tag4", ""],
                            ["starts-with", "$x-goog-meta-tag5", ""],
                            ["content-length-range", 0, 30000000]
                            ]               
                        }'''


                    policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)
```

What is the best way to send the "policy" to the front end using Google Cloud endpoint? Currently I am using the [messages.StringField](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/fieldclasses) using -

```
API_Get_Policy_Document_Response_obj.policy             = policy
```

when I use the "policy" to do a HTTP Post, I get an error reading the policy document. The error I get is -

> InvalidPolicyDocumentThe content of the form does not meet the
>   conditions specified in the policy document.Policy document parsing
>   error: Lexical Error: Unmatched Input:

What is the best way to send an encoded String from backend (python) to front end (Andorid) using Google Cloud Endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud endpoint with GCM. the full scope of it would be too long a post but I would direct you to this
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addgcm
The document is a little Eclipse centric but it does the trick